# What is the meaning of having the autocorelation function a cut of at a specific lag and at the same time the partial autocorrelation tails off

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, moving-average, partial-correlation

having the case that the ACF have only, for example on spike at lag 1 , and the PACF decays exponentially this is a MA model signature.
but what is the meaning of having the a value at a the lag K on PACF and not having a sppike at the same lag in the ACF.
In another word if the PACF is is the amount of correlation between a variable and a lag of itself after removing the effect of all lower-order-lags on both values, how comes that there's no intermidate lags effects (as ACF tells us) and there's a value for PACF?
[image]

And why this is a MA signature?

Comment: The ACF tells you the MA model, the PACF the AR model, so there is correlation of errors for lag 1, and there is correlation of values for 3 lags. This could also be an ARMA model.

Answer (score 0):

It is an MA signature because the # of significant PAC is greater than the # of significant ACF i.e. the PAC dominates.

See http://autobox.com/cms/index.php/afs-university/autobox-examples/modeling-with-autobox#_Toc509396185 for more hints on model identification.

Comment: My question is what makes PACF have values on the other hand ACF do not have values at the same lag, this do not make sens for me as the definition of PACF comes from ACF after removing the effect of intermediate lags

Comment: Another point, MA(1) model is defined as: 
ACF : spike at lag 1, no correlation for other lags
PACF : damps out exponentially http://www.statsoft.com/Textbook/Time-Series-Analysis

Comment: both the acf and the pacf are fundamentally regression coefficients and conditional regression coefficents respectively Estimation can yield non-zero values BUT they can also be not statistically significant from 0.0 . nonsigniifvant.